# Manage booking policy of resources in Exchange 2013 via Managed Api

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I want to manage the booking policy of a room, maximum duration of a meeting for example. Do someone has idea how do you do that via Managed API?

Answer (score 0):

The managed API cannot police max duration but what you need todo is validate the entry before you submit a reservation...

```
                    public override bool IsNoOverTimeLimit(Reservation reservation)
                    {
                        return reservation.End.Subtract(reservation.Start).TotalMinutes <= 120;
                    }
                    if(!IsNoOverTimeLimit)
                    {
                        var errorMsg = new Label();
                        var fontSize = FontUnit.Point(10);
                        errorMsg.Font.Size = fontSize;
                        errorMsg.Text = "Reservation time is limited to " + ((float)30 / 60).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " hours at a time.<br /> ";
                        placeHolder.Controls.Add(errorMsg);
                    }
```

My version is way more complicated than this but you get the point. Just simply check the reservation before you submit and if over time limit, return to page with some pretty warning..